# h264_cuvid @ 0x55e14e670bb0 ctx->cvdl->cuvidGetDecoderCaps(&ctx->caps8) failed

Tags: ffmpeg, gpu, codec

I have ubuntu18.04,  NVIDIA GTX1060, NVIDIA driver 11.4, cuda version 10.2, cudnn version7.6.5.

Yesterday, I got it done with following configuration and it worked perfectly with my test video(ffmpeg 4.3.4 +nv-codec-headers10.0):

./configure --prefix=/usr/local/ffmpeg --disable-asm --disable-x86asm 
--enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-nvenc 
--enable-nonfree --enable-libnpp 
--extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/cuda/include 
--extra-cflags=-fPIC --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 
--enable-gpl --enable-libx264  --enable-libx265 
--enable-shared 
--enable-libass 
--enable-libfdk-aac 
--enable-libfreetype 
--enable-libmp3lame 
--enable-libopus 
--enable-libtheora 
--enable-libvorbis

However, today I want to try another version of nv-codec-headers, and I use the exactly same configuration, it gives me these errors:
[h264_cuvid @ 0x55e14e670bb0] ctx->cvdl->cuvidGetDecoderCaps(&ctx->caps8) failed
[h264_cuvid @ 0x55e14e670bb0] ctx->cvdl->cuvidGetDecoderCaps(&ctx->caps10) failed
[h264_cuvid @ 0x55e14e670bb0] ctx->cvdl->cuvidGetDecoderCaps(&ctx->caps12) failed
Stream mapping:
Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (h264_cuvid) -> h264 (h264_nvenc))
Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
Error while opening decoder for input stream #0:0 : Generic error in an external library

Right after this error occurred, I was never able to make it work again. No matter what version I choose, or what configuration I use, it just didn't work, always the same errors. I couldn't use GPU to accelerate the video encoding/decoding anymore.

What should do?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It looks like the question should be "how to restore nv-codec-headers 10.0 in Ubuntu 18.04?". It looks like the error is related to "external library", and not to FFmpeg...

Comment: I followed the instruction for compiling nv-codec-headers, and I tried both 10.0 and 8.0, they both didn't work. Since the steps of nv-codec-headers compilation are pretty simple, I couldn't find out any operation to fix it.

Comment: Problem solved! It appears to be the cuda file's problem.  I go to /usr/local/cuda/lib64, there is no libnvcuvid.so.470.129.06, and no libnvidia-encode.so.470.129.06, so ffmpeg cannot find the right files. I copied these two files from usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/, and created soft link files .so, .so.1, and it finally worked

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. The `libnvcuvid.so` was broken. Copy `libnvcuvid.so` from the system to the cuda directory was what solved this for me:

```
sudo cp /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvcuvid.so /usr/local/cuda-11.7/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnvcuvid.so
```

Comment: Worked for me thanks :)